# Basic Page - Associated Image Field

Tags: theming, media, entities

I created an Image Field for the Basic Page Content Type.

I want to control the output of this image to use as a banner with a caption on top. Is there a function to render out a field specific to the page,

such as `<?php print render($page['my_image_field']); ?>`.

I wan't to style this separately from the body content.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this within a tpl file specific to your content type. In this case it sounds like it'd be node--page.tpl.php

All the drupal 7 template naming suggestions are available at - https://drupal.org/node/1089656

Just make sure you have a regular node.tpl.php file in your theme before creating the new one.

From there this thread tells you how to go about printing your field elsewhere (specific to drupal 7)- https://drupal.org/node/1059636

Specific to your question:

```
<?php
hide($content['field_my_image_field']);
print render($content);
?>
```

then wherever you want your image to appear at use

```
<?php
print render($content['field_my_image_field']); 
?>
```